# WPF caliburn StartDesignTime never called

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, designer, caliburn

**Caliburn version: 2.0.2.0** and **VisualStudio 2015**

**Short Version**

Why is StartDesignTime of BootstrapperBase never called. Or how is it possible to execute code in design time to initialize a MVVM framework?

**Long Version**

Caliburn is not able to find the view model during design. I debugged the designer, and it seems that the framework is never initialized. The method StartDesignTime of the Bootstrapper is never called.

My understanding was that the ctor of the Bootstrapper should be called during the initialization of the Application.Resources.

```
<Application x:Class="CityMixServiceGui.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:cityMixServiceGui="clr-namespace:CityMixServiceGui">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <cityMixServiceGui:ServiceGuiBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
    public ServiceGuiBootstrapper()
    {
        m_adqDeviceConnector = new AdqDeviceConnector();
        Initialize(); //  this call is required during design time but never called
    }
```

**What I've tried**

- Ugly workaround and created a Bootstrapper in the ViewModel ctor, Because the   ctor of the design time view model seems to be the only code called by the designer.

In the MainViewModel I call this method of the Bootstrapper

```
public static void InitializeForDesigner()
{
    if (null == s_designerInstance)
    {
        s_designerInstance = new ServiceGuiBootstrapper();
        s_designerInstance.Initialize();
    }
}
```

And if have set the design time DC and the "cal:Bind.AtDesignTime" property

```
    <UserControl x:Class="CityMixServiceGui.MainWindowView"
    //snip
          d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel,  IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
          cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">
```

- I've tried to implement this solution here:
  [Assembly-level initialization at design time](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/assembly-level-initialization-at-design-time/)
  But unfortunately this seems not to work anymore with the VS2015 designer.

**[Edit]**

I believe that the "normal" behavior is that the constructor in App.xaml normaly calls the ctor of the bootstrapper.
See: [Win8 Bug](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/2)

This bug was fixed, but it seems that something similar happens in VS2015 with 2.0.2.0

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure about the source which told you that you should manually call the view model ctor, but, as per [documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design-Time%20Support), you should set a design time data context which, from your code, I infer that you haven't.

Comment: thanks for your hint, but I set the design data context in the XAML. the last code snippet - am I missing something?
I don't try to  manually call the VM ctor. I try to initialize the bootstrapper. See my edit

Comment: Refer to the updated documentation in  caliburnmicro.com. codeplex is bit outdated, currently, latest development is hosted with [github](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/)

Comment: I've installed Caliburn.Micro.Start and the behavior there is the same. The bootstrapper is never instantiated and therefore the StartDesignTime is never called

Comment: Checking the source hints that `ViewModel.View.IsInDesignMode` is checked before calling that method, see if the view is actually set.